# assertEqual compare json objects raise error because of 'quote' in Python

Tags: python, json, unit-testing, python-unittest, assertion

I have a function which converts a dataframe to a json object

```
def convert_to_json(dataframe):
   
    output_json = json.dumps({"XYZ": dataframe.to_dict('records')}, default=str)

    return output_json
```

Then in my unit test:

```
    def test_convert_to_json(self):
       test_data = {
            'col_2': ['2018-03-02', '2018-03-01'],
            'col_3': ['12345678', '12345678'],
            'col_4': [31, 31],
            'col_5': [0.035133, 0.035133]
          }
       test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
       test_json = xxx.convert_to_json(self.test_df)
       
       expected_json = {"XYZ": [{"col_2": "2018-03-02", "col_3": "12345678", "col_4": 31, "col_5": 0.035133}, {"col_2": "2018-03-01", "col_3": "12345678", "col_4": 31, "col_5": 0.035133}]}
        
       self.assertEqual(test_json, expected_json)
```

This test failed because of the quote:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.008s

FAILED (failures=1)


{'XYZ': [{'col_2': '2018-03-02',
                                 'col_3': '12345678',
                                 'col_4': 31,
                                 'col_5': 0.035133},
                                {'col_2': '2018-03-01',
                                 'col_3': '12345678',
                                 'col_4': 31,
                                 'col_5': 0.035133}]} != {"XYZ": [{"col_2": "2018-03-02", "col_3": "12345678", "col_4": 31, "col_5": 0.035133}, {"col_2": "2018-03-01", "col_3": "12345678", "col_4": 31, "col_5": 0.035133}]}
```

However, if I print out the value for `test_json` and `expected_json`, they both use double quotes:

```
{"XYZ": [{"col_2": "2018-03-02", "col_3": "12345678", "col_4": 31, "col_5": 0.035133}, {"col_2": "2018-03-01", "col_3": "12345678", "col_4": 31, "col_5": 0.035133}]}

{"XYZ": [{"col_2": "2018-03-02", "col_3": "12345678", "col_4": 31, "col_5": 0.035133}, {"col_2": "2018-03-01", "col_3": "12345678", "col_4": 31, "col_5": 0.035133}]}
```

I'm new to unit test, very confused about the code behavior, can someone help please? Thanks.

Comment: `test_json` is a string. `expected_json` is a dict. A string is not equal to a dict. Even if they look similar when printed.

Comment: ah... how can I fix it? I tried `self.assertEqual(test_json.to_dict(), expected_json)` but it gave me error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
`

Comment: I also tried `self.assertEqual(json.load(test_json), expected_json)` still not working....

Comment: It worked when I do `self.assertEqual(json.loads(test_json), json.loads(expected_json))`, does this mean there is something wrong in the original function?

Comment: What do you want to assert? That two strings are equal or that two dictionaries are equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @khelwood mentioned, you are comparing a string and a dict. I would suggest you to change the `expected_json` variable to string (do it only if that is really what you are expecting to get from the tested function, of course).

Try this:

```py
expected_json = '{"XYZ": [{"col_2": "2018-03-02", "col_3": "12345678", "col_4": 31, "col_5": 0.035133}, {"col_2": "2018-03-01", "col_3": "12345678", "col_4": 31, "col_5": 0.035133}]}'
```

(Note the single quotes surrounding the value)